# Code modification for an array of numbers to be read from pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code: `value` represents an array of numbers. I want to arrange all numbers while also keeping track of the max and min.

```
if (value > stats_max)
    stats_max = value;
if (value < stats_min)
    stats_min = value;
```

can I do:

```
if ((value > stats_min) && (value < stats_max))
     stats_mid = value;
```

just to print one value.

what should I do to write all those "values" in an array?

Comment: What does _`value` are many in numbers_ mean?

Comment: He means it represents an array -- I think. In short you must iterate over the array elements `0 - (n-1)` to print, test, sum, etc.. You access individual elements with `value[x]` where `x` is in the range `0 - (n-1)`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Elaborate it first.

Comment: Do you like to find minimum and maximum of your values? Or do you like to sort your values? What's expected in the `stats_mid`?

Comment: @iharob : may be I could not explain all my scenario here and everyone is confused. sorry for creating this confusion.

Comment: @Shreevardhan : you are right. the thing I want need long background to be explained as I am looking code with many structures and arrays. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For example, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int values[] = { 9, 5, 1, 7, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 0};
    size_t size = sizeof(values)/sizeof(*values);
    int *value = values;
    int stats_max, stats_min;
    size_t i;

    stats_max = stats_min = *value;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++value){
        if (*value > stats_max)
            stats_max = *value;
        if (*value < stats_min)
            stats_min = *value;
    }
    printf("max = %d, min = %d\n", stats_max, stats_min);
    return 0;
}
```